# Insert in regex expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have following string:

```
10-5*tan(40)-cos(0)-40*sin(90);
```

I have extracted the math functions and calculated their values:

```
tan(40) = 1.42;
cos(0) = 1;
sin(90) = 0;
```

I want to insert these values back into the expression string as:

```
10-5*(1.42)-(1)-40*(0);
```

Please assist

Comment: 4 questions with no any answer marked, you need to mark answer if someone take effort to answer your questions

Answer (score 1):

I would use Regex.Replace and then use a custom MatchEvaluator to convert your values and insert these, check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx

Which would look something like:

```
class Program
{
    static string ConvertMathFunc(Match m)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["mathfunc"]);
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["argument"]);

        double arg;
        if (!double.TryParse(m.Groups["argument"].Value, out arg))
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Math function argument could not be parsed to double", m.Groups["argument"].Value));

        switch (m.Groups["mathfunc"].Value)
        {
            case "tan": return Math.Tan(arg).ToString();
            case "cos": return Math.Cos(arg).ToString();
            case "sin": return Math.Sin(arg).ToString();
            default:
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Unknown math function '{0}'", m.Groups["mathfunc"].Value));
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "10 - 5 * tan(40) - cos(0) - 40 * sin(90);";

        Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<mathfunc>(tan|cos|sin))\((?<argument>[0-9]+)\)");
        string output = pattern.Replace(input, new MatchEvaluator(Program.ConvertMathFunc));

        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```